JAWS reading the error message twice in lightning input LWC
JAWS reads the error message on the lightnin input twice because of the presence of both aria-errormessage and aria-describedby attributes. Values for both attrubutes are same.
How to resolve this and make JAWS read the error message only once. I have tried to removing one of the attributes but I can not access the "input element" from the DOM.

